# Git log -G, but over many repos

Tags: git

I have a directory containing many git repos.

I want to run `git log -G FooBar` over all these git repos.

The output should be sorted by the datetime of the commit.

Answer (score -3):

A bit ugly, but works:

```
for repo in *; do (
    cd $repo; 
    echo $repo; 
    git log -G FooBar --pretty=format:"%ad %h in $repo by %an, %s" --date=iso --since=2020-01-01  >> /tmp/git-log-FooBar; 
    echo >> /tmp/git-log-FooBar  ) ; done; sort -rn /tmp/git-log-FooBar | head
```

Better solutions are welcome.

Source: [Güttli's Git Tips](https://github.com/guettli/git-tips/blob/main/README.md#git-log-over-many-git-repos)

Comment: Rather than spawning a subshell that `cd`s, you can use `git -C <dir>` to let Git do `chdir` instead.